# Windows Batch: How to keep empty lines with loop for /f

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delimiter, blank-line

I'm searching how to keep empty lines when I browse a file with a for loop.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[" %%i in ('type "test1.txt" ^| find /v /n ""') do (
SET tmp=%%i
echo !tmp! >> test2.txt
)
```

Actually it works for everybody, but as far as I'm concerned it does not work.
For instance if test1.txt content is:

```
Hello I come from France
I live in Paris

I'm sorry I don't know English, could we speak French please?
If it doesn't bother you

Thank you
```

Result in test2.txt will be:

```
[1 
[2 
[3 
[4 
[5 
[6 
[7
```

If I put off the "1" near the star "*", result is:

```
[1]Hello I come from France 
[2]I live in Paris 
[3] 
[4]I'm sorry I don't know English, could we speak French please? 
[5]If it doesn't bother you 
[6] 
[7]Thank you
```

Desired output is:

```
Hello I come from France
I live in Paris

I'm sorry I don't know English, could we speak French please?
If it doesn't bother you

Thank you
```

Can you please help me to solve this trouble?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be done as

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%a in ('
        find /n /v "" ^< "file1.txt"
    ') do (
        >> "file2.txt" echo(%%b
    )
```

The output from the inner `find` command is like

```
[123]texttexttext
```

The code uses the closing bracket as delimiter, so the tokens (we are requesting two tokens: `1,*` or `1*`) are

```
[123 texttexttext
^    ^
1    2
%%a  %%b
```

But, as repeated delimiters are handled as only one delimiter, if one line begins with a closing bracket it will be removed. This can be prevented
as

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=0123456789" %%a in ('
        find /n /v "" ^< "file1.txt"
    ') do (
        set "line=%%b"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"file2.txt" echo(!line:~1!
        endlocal
    )
```

Here the numbers are used as delimiters and the line is tokenized as

```
[   ]texttexttext
^   ^
%%a %%b
```

Then the value of the second token is stored inside a variable, with *delayed expansion disabled* to avoid problems with exclamations inside the data (that will be handled/replaced by the parser if delayed expansion is active)

Once the data is inside the variable, delayed expansion is activated (something needed as we want to retrieve the contents from a variable changed inside a block of code) to output the line from the second position (first character in string is 0) to remove the closing bracket. Once done, delayed expansion is disabled again.

**edited** as the OP has to incorporate it to a larger/complex script, this code should face the most usual problems

```dos
@echo off
    rem For this test we will have delayed expansion from the start
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem External code block that will make delayed expansion necessary
    if 1==1 ( 
        rem Variables changed inside block
        set "input_file=file1.txt"
        set "output_file=file2.txt"

        rem Grab a reference to the content of the file variables
        for %%i in ("!input_file!") do for %%o in ("!output_file!") do (

            rem Prepare the environment for file work
            setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

            rem Prepare output file
            type nul > "%%~fo"

            rem Process input file and write to output file
            for /f "tokens=1,* delims=0123456789" %%a in ('
                find /n /v "" ^< "%%~fi"
            ') do (
                set "line=%%b"
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                >>"%%~fo" echo(!line:~1!
                endlocal
            )

            rem Restore the previous environment
            endlocal
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer works. But there something I didn't expect. I need to do it on a bigger file, and it has special caracters. I noticed that it didn't copy exclamation mark "!" and "^". Maybe I should have precised since the begining that I needed to use it with special caracters. For instance, this line: !(^bytes=[^,]+(,[^,]+){0,4}$|^$) is copied like this : (bytes=[,]+(,[,]+){0,4}$|$)

Comment: @Cainzer, This will only happen if you have delayed expansion enabled before entering the `for /f` loop. That is the reason for the `setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion` in the posted code. As indicated in the answer *delayed expansion* needs to be disabled.

Comment: Ok. Does it delete other variables that I used previously with delayed expansion enabled ? I mean variables which were not in the loop, but before in my code...

Comment: @Cainzer, no, place a `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion` before the `for` command and an `endlocal` after the `for`. Only changes made inside the `for` loop will be discarded. Or you can wrap the code inside the `do` clause between the `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion/endlocal`

Comment: All right, I'll test and valide your answer if it's ok. I did it with a test loop and it seemed ok. Let's do it in real batch now. Thank you very much

Comment: So yes I'm facing to something new.
How to do if "file1.txt" is a variable ? For example : !FILE_NAME!

Comment: @Cainzer, I've included in the answer a sample showing a wait to deal with it.

Comment: Your answer is an interesting variant that I have never seen before. I'm used to seeing the loop as`for /f "delims=" ...`, and the line number prefix is stripped by using `echo(!line:*]=!`. I feel like your variant is a bit more complex, but both techniques yield the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slightly different variant using the [`findstr` command](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) rather than `find` and doing the [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to the output file `file2.txt` only once rather than per `for /F` loop iteration:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
>> "file2.txt" (
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "file1.txt"') do (
        set "line=%%a"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!line:*:=!
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
```

The `findstr` command precedes every line by a line number and a colon, like this:

> ```cmd
> 1:Hello I come from France
> ```

The [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) portion `!line:*:=!` replaces everything up to the first colon (due to `*`) by nothing, thus removing this.

Replace the `>>` operator by `>` in case you want to overwrite an already existing file rather than to append to it.

Answer (score 0):

Send your loop command to **`con:`** device:

- In command line:

---

```cmd
for /F tokens^=^* %F in ('type File.txt ^>con:')do @echo/%F
```

---

- In your bat file:

```cmd
for /F tokens^=^* %%F in ('type File.txt ^>con:')do echo;%%F
```

---