# preserve empty lines in a text file while using batch for /f

Tags: batch-file

I have been trying to find and replace a string in a text file using batch script. I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra/23076141#23076141) which almost solved my issue, but the empty lines were not preserved in the output file. I have tried [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314203/windows-batch-how-to-keep-empty-lines-with-loop-for-f) but lines start with line numbers  []... [17]

Any help to to extend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra/23076141#23076141) to preserve empty lines in the output file would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=<Tool>"
set "replace=XYZ"

set "textFile=C:\abc.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%textFile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

The output looks like:
[image]

Comment: You need to show the code you tried in your question.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks you for the comment, I have added the code which I tried.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did not study the answer at your 2nd link hard enough - it has a solution that works perfectly well.

I prefer a variant of that technique that uses `*]=` replacement instead of substring:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=<Tool>"
set "replace=XYZ"

set "textFile=C:\abc.txt"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^| find /v /n "" ^& break ^> "%textFile%"') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:*]=!"
    if defined line set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!
    endlocal
)
```

But the code is not optimized - the append redirection slows things down because the output file must be opened and the file pointer positioned to the end-of-file for each iteration of the loop. It is much faster to redirect to a temporary file once, outside of the loop, and then use MOVE to replace the original with the temp.

I also prefer to use FINDSTR instead of FIND - it handles long lines better, and does not need a pipe or redirection.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=<Tool>"
set "replace=XYZ"

set "textFile=C:\abc.txt"

>"%textFile%.new" (
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" "%textFile%"') do (
      set "line=%%i"
      setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
      set "line=!line:*:=!"
      if defined line set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
      echo(!line!
      endlocal
  )
)
move /y "%textFile%.new" "%textFile%" >nul
```

Truth be told, I never use pure batch to modify text files anymore. There are too many edge cases that take a lot of arcane code to work around. There are still many potential issues with the above code. For example:

- The search string cannot contain `=`
- The search string cannot begin with `*` or `!`
- The replace string cannot contain `!`
- The replacement can fail if the search and/or replace contain both `"` as well as poison characters like `&`, `|` etc.

I use the [JREPL.BAT regular expression find/replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) instead. It is faster, more robust, and much more powerful. It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward, without any need for 3rd party exe files.

For example, the following simple command does your literal find/replace very quickly.

```
call jrepl "<Tool>" "XYZ" /l /f "C:\abc.txt" /o -
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. It worked :) I also tried FINDSTR instead of FIND, I was getting some strange output.. But, your solution worked as expected..:)

Comment: Hi @dbenham, can you please tell what does echo(!line! do? I mean what is use of '(' in this?

Comment: @atul_pant - There are a number of edge cases where `echo !line!` and other more frequently seen forms can fail - meaning something is printed other than the content of the variable. Via experimentation by a number of people, it has been determined that `echo(` is the only form that is guaranteed to work regardless what follows. I know it is ugly, but it works.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation which tells that what exactly '(' do after echo? Just like we use ! around variable name if delayed expansion is enabled, is there similar meaning of '(' when used with echo, like it is done above?