# Batch: 'FOR' cmd works partially, 'skip=' option not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a script that sets specific values, then writes each value into a new line of a text document. After that it should read the document and set new values to a specified line of the text document, then echo those out.

I have tried different values for "skip=#" which didn't change anything. When I tried to not use the "skip=0" option in the first `FOR` and that makes the batch echo out "Value three" for all values. (Quick edit: I've used [this website](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) for information on it so far.)

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Setting values
SET @valueone=Value one
SET @valuetwo=Value two
SET @valuethree=Value three

REM Saving values
IF EXIST "values.txt" DEL "values.txt"
echo %@valueone% >values.txt
echo %@valuetwo% >>values.txt
echo %@valuethree% >>values.txt

REM Reading values again and echoing them at at the same time.
REM This was separated (first reading then echoing) but it didn't change anything.
FOR /F "skip=0 delims=" %%i IN (values.txt) DO SET @valueonefinal=%%i
echo Value number one:
echo %@valueonefinal%
echo.
FOR /F "skip=1 delims=" %%i IN (values.txt) DO SET @valuetwofinal=%%i
echo Value number two:
echo %@valuetwofinal%
echo.
FOR /F "skip=2 delims=" %%i IN (values.txt) DO SET @valuethreefinal=%%i
echo Value number three:
echo %@valuethreefinal%
pause
```

Expected output in the console:

```
Value number one:
Value one

Value number two:
Value two

Value number three:
Value three
```

Actual output:

```
 delims=" was unexpected at this time.
Value number one:
ECHO is off.

Value number two:
Value three

Value number three:
Value three
```

I'm not that experienced but I suspect that I may be doing the "skip=#" part wrong. Any help with this is greatly apprechiated!

Comment: `skip=0` is not accepted by `for /F`, the number must be greater than `0`; just remove the `skip` option to skip no lines...

Comment: Your problem is that you are parsing the File from Top to bottom, and skipping the First value, what you don't realize is that FOR will set the value to the LAST item it found.  This means that the script as written can only ever return the last item in the values file.  To deal with this you could reverse the order of the values file (or reverse sort it in line) or you could remove values as they are matched, or you could break the loop on the first match and return that result.

Comment: @aschipfl That's what I suspected, thanks for clarifying. However, when I do that all outputs that are echoed state "Value three". Is the `FOR` command not reading the correct line or am I just using it wrong?

Comment: @BenPersonick I did not know that the `FOR` command sets it to the last line from the text file, that is where I went wrong. Thank you for telling me. I feel like letting the batch create multiple text-files would be easier. Sure, a bit messier, but easier to do, if my logic is correct.

Comment: To assign line number `X` to a variable then replace `set @valueonefinal=%%i` by `if defined @valueonefinal set "@valueonefinal=%%i"` and use the option `skip=X-1` (omit `skip=0` in case); the `for` loop executes its body for all but the skipped lines, except empty ones or such beginning with the `eol` character which defaults to `;`...

Comment: @Puntherline  No problem, I'm glad to help.  I wrote up a version of the script which would allow you to find any arbitrary value the most quickly possible (skip X, exit from the loop.) for you as an answer as well.  Hope that helps as well. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option `skip=0` is not accepted by the [`for /F` command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html), the specified number must be in the range from 1 to 2<sup>31</sup> − 1. To skip no lines just do not provide the `skip` option at all.

---

You seem to try to assign the text of a certain line to a variable (for instance, the third one):

```cmd
FOR /F "skip=2 delims=" %%i IN (values.txt) DO SET @valuethreefinal=%%i
```

Well, this actually assigns the content of the last line to the variable, because the `set` command in the body of the loop is executed for all but the skipped lines. More precisely said, the `for /F` loop iterates over all non-empty lines which do not begin with `;` which is the default character of the `eol` option.

To actually assign the third line to the variable you need to change the code:

```cmd
rem // Ensure that the variable is initially unset somewhere before:
set "@valuethreefinal="
rem // As soon as the variable is set the `if` condition is no longer going to be fulfilled:
for /F "usebackq skip=2 delims=" %%i in ("values.txt") do if not defined @valuethreefinal set "@valuethreefinal=%%i"
```

This does not necessarily assign the third line to the variable, it actually assigns the text of the first line after the (two) skipped ones that is not empty and does not begin with `;` (remember the `eol` character).

The `usebackq` option allows to put quotation marks around the file name. This is not necessary in your situation, but it is when a file name contains <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> or other special characters.

I used the undocumented quoted `set` syntax here because this is safer than the unquoted one, particularly when it comes to special characters and also to avoid unintended trailing white-spaces.

---

To disable the `eol` character you could use the undocumented unquoted option string syntax:

```cmd
for /F usebackq^ skip^=2^ delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("values.txt") do if not defined @valuethreefinal set "@valuethreefinal=%%i"
```

As you can see the <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> and `=`-signs are [escaped](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) by the caret symbol `^` in order to treat the whole option string as a unit.

This still skips over empty lines though. To prevent this take a loop at this thread: [preserve empty lines in a text file while using batch for /f](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38723595).

---

Since you want to capture more than a single line you could extend the code to the following:

```cmd
set "@valueonefinal=" & set "@valuethreefinal=" & set "@valuethreefinal="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("values.txt") do (
    if not defined @valueonefinal (
        set "@valueonefinal=%%i"
    ) else (
        if not defined @valuetwofinal (
            set "@valuetwofinal=%%i"
        ) else (
            if not defined @valuethreefinal (
                set "@valuethreefinal=%%i"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This can be compressed to:

```cmd
set "@valueonefinal=" & set "@valuethreefinal=" & set "@valuethreefinal="
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("values.txt") do (
    if not defined @valueonefinal (
        set "@valueonefinal=%%i"
    ) else if not defined @valuetwofinal (
        set "@valuetwofinal=%%i"
    ) else if not defined @valuethreefinal (
        set "@valuethreefinal=%%i"
    )
)
```

---

A more flexible method is to use [pseudo-arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167990):

```cmd
rem // Initialise an index counter:
set /A "INDEX=0"
rem // Assign every line to an element of a pseudo-array:
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%i in ("values.txt") do (
    rem // Increment the index counter:
    set /A "INDEX+=1"
    rem // Assign the current line to a pseudo-array element:
    call set "@valuefinal[%%INDEX%%]=%%i"
)
```

The (non-empty) lines of the file `value.txt` are now assigned to variables called `@valuefinal[1]`, `@valuefinal[2]`, `@valuefinal[3]`, etc. (there is no concept of arrays in batch scripting, the variables are exactly the same as yours, `@valueonefinal`, etc., that is why I use the term "pseudo").

The [`call` command](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) is used here in order to be able to write and read the variable `INDEX` within the same block of code; just using `set "@valuefinal[%INDEX%]=%%i"` would result in assigning and therefore overwriting the variable `@valuefinal[0]` in every loop iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me in such great detail and explaining further functions! Now that I know how to actually do that I realize that I was further away from the solution than I first thought so thank you for filling me in.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are parsing the File from Top to bottom, and skipping the First value, what you don't realize is that FOR will set the value to the LAST item it found.  This means that the script as written can only ever return the last item in the values file.

To deal with this you could:

- Break the loop on the first match and return that result.
- Remove values as they are matched

I like to Break the loop.

First let me make you code a little more streamlined so we can re-write it multiple times to show each

This is going to work exactly as your existing code but now we can easily add more values and loop them in a quick go.

### Your Original Code Refactored:

```cmd
@( SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_ValuesFile=%~dp0values.txt"
  REM Remove Old Values File
  DEL /F /Q "!_ValuesFile!" >NUL 2>NUL
  REM Saving values
  FOR %%A IN (one two three) DO (
    ECHO.Value %%A>>"!_ValuesFile!" )
)

CALL :Main

( PAUSE
  ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B 0
)

:Main
  FOR /L %%L IN (0,1,2) DO ( 
    CALL SET /A "_Value=%%L + 1"
    ECHO.&ECHO.------ Iteration: %%L ------&ECHO.Value number !_Value!:
    IF %%L EQU 0 ( SET "_ForOptions=tokens=*" ) ELSE (
      SET "_ForOptions=Skip=%%L tokens=*" )
    CALL :Loop %%L
  )
GOTO :EOF

:Loop
  FOR /F "%_ForOptions%" %%i IN (' type "%_ValuesFile%"
  ') DO ( CALL SET "@value%_Value%final=%%i" )
  ECHO.!@value%_Value%final!
GOTO :EOF
```

### * Break the Loop on the First Match:

```cmd
@( SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_ValuesFile=%~dp0values.txt"
  REM Remove Old Values File
  DEL /F /Q "!_ValuesFile!" >NUL 2>NUL
  REM Saving values
  FOR %%A IN (one two three) DO (
    ECHO.Value %%A>>"!_ValuesFile!" )
)

CALL :Main

( PAUSE
  ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B 0
)

:Main
  FOR /L %%L IN (0,1,2) DO ( 
    CALL SET /A "_Value=%%L + 1"
    ECHO.&ECHO.------ Iteration: %%L ------&ECHO.Value number !_Value!:
    IF %%L EQU 0 ( SET "_ForOptions=tokens=*" ) ELSE (
      SET "_ForOptions=Skip=%%L tokens=*" )
    CALL :Loop %%L

  )
  ECHO.&ECHO.------ Final Values After %%L Iterations: ------
  SET @value
GOTO :EOF

:Loop
  FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%A IN ('
    CMD /C "FOR /F %_ForOptions% %%i IN (' type "%_ValuesFile%" ') DO @(ECHO.%%i&exit /b)"
  ') DO @(
    SET "@value%_Value%final=%%~A"
  )
  ECHO.!@value%_Value%final!
GOTO :EOF
```

### Example Output from Break the Loop Version:

```cmd
Y:\>C:\Admin\S-O_Value-Checker_v2.cmd

------ Iteration: 0 ------
Value number 1:
Value one

------ Iteration: 1 ------
Value number 2:
Value two

------ Iteration: 2 ------
Value number 3:
Value three

------ Final Values After %L Iterations: ------
@value1final=Value one
@value2final=Value two
@value3final=Value three
Press any key to continue . . .
```